# Rails find only related values from db

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord, find

I have a rails model `Contractors` which has a `has_many` relation with `services`.

I have another model `Companies` and companies can select services and the selected services get added to an array `services` in the `companies` table.

I'm trying to get a list of all `services` selected by a `company` for a specific `contractor` and I'm doing the following:

```
@services = @contractors.services.find(@company.services)
```

But it throws an error if the `services` list contains even a single service which is not made by that contractor. Is there a way I can make it ignore all `services` which were not made by the specific contractor?

Comment: Are you trying to find a contractor that has any services matching some services a Company is looking for?

Comment: I basically have a contractor page on which I want to display the list of contractor services which are also in the `services` array of a specific company

Answer (score 1, accepted):

can you not simply use the where clause? I am guessing @contractors is actually a single contractor Active Record Object.

`@services = @contractors.services.where(id: @company.services)`

Answer (score 1):

Make sure in table `Services` we have `contractor_id` and `company_id`.

Check relation between these tables.

And it's simple, just need

```
@services = @company.services.where(contractor_id: xxx)
```

a `company` has_many `services`, a `service` belongs_to `contractor` and you must use `.where` when you want to get many records

Answer (score 1):

1. Try this :

   `@services = @contractors.services.find(@company.services.map(&:id))`

This version of code give exceptions if service is not available into `@contractors.services`

2. Try this one without exceptions:

   `@services = @contractors.services.find_by_id(@company.services.map(&:id))`